# How to fix scrapy respose.xpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query' in python scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying my hands at some very simple web scraping.

Initially I tested all my xpath returns in scrapy's shell environment but upon running them in my spider class I receive the following error.

```
TypeError: xpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

**SOME CODE TO DEMONSTRATE**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request #may be irrelevant 
from scrapy.http import TextResponse as response #may be irrelevant 

class hotpads_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hotpad_listing'
    base = ["https://www.hotpads.com"]

    #Get all listings that are for rent by owner
    start_urls = ["https://www.hotpads.com/portland-or/for-rent-by-owner?isListedByOwner=true&lat=45.5659&lon=-122.6507&z=11"]

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//div[@class="SeoFooterLinks-link Utils-text-overflow"]//a/@href').getall()

        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.base[0] + link
            #print(absolute_url) #unit testing
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url,callback=self.parse_meta)

        #get the next page of results
        #next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="Linker PagerItem"]/@href').extract()
        #next_absolute_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)

        #yield scrapy.Request(next_absolute_url, callback = self.parse)

    def parse_meta(self,resposne):
        #median_rent = response.xpath('//td[@class="AreaMarketInfo-table-data"]//text()').getall()[0]
        #monthly_chng = response.xpath('//td[@class="AreaMarketInfo-table-data"]//text()').getall()[1]
        location = response.css(" div.ExploreWrapper > div > div.Title.ExploreWrapper-title.Title-lg")[0].css("*::text").get()
        #location = response.xpath('//div[@class="Title ExploreWrapper-title  Title-lg"]/text()').get() ## this is just the xpath version of the previous variable for testing
        yield {
            'location':location
            #'median_rent' : median_rent , 
            #'monthly_chng':monthly_chng
        }
```

Now I have commented out a fair amount of my code because this error persists across all of the variables.

Here is what I've tried.

```
scrapy shell "https://www.hotpads.com/portland-or/for-rent-by-owner?isListedByOwner=true&lat=45.5659&lon=-122.6507&z=11"
response.css(" div.ExploreWrapper > div > div.Title.ExploreWrapper-title.Title-lg")[0].css("*::text").get()
>>'Portland snapshot'
```

Edit:

Here is truncated output from my crawler.

```
2019-04-29 12:04:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-29 12:04:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-04-29 12:04:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
2019-04-29 12:04:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://hotpads.com/portland-or/for-rent-by-owner?isListedByOwner=true&lat=45.5659&lon=-122.6507&z=11> from <GET https://www.hotpads.com/portland-or/for-rent-by-owner?isListedByOwner=true&lat=45.5659&lon=-122.6507&z=11>
2019-04-29 12:04:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://hotpads.com/portland-or/for-rent-by-owner?isListedByOwner=true&lat=45.5659&lon=-122.6507&z=11> (referer: None)
2019-04-29 12:04:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://hotpads.com/97203/for-rent-by-owner> from <GET https://www.hotpads.com/97203/for-rent-by-owner>
2019-04-29 12:04:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://hotpads.com/97203/for-rent-by-owner> (referer: None)
2019-04-29 12:04:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://hotpads.com/97203/for-rent-by-owner> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\zdwhi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\zdwhi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\zdwhi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\zdwhi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\zdwhi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\zdwhi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\thinkful projects\Scraping Exercise\craigslist\craigslist\spiders\hotpad_listing.py", line 33, in parse_meta
    location = response.xpath('//div[@class="Title ExploreWrapper-title  Title-lg"]/text()').get()
TypeError: xpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `def parse_meta(self,resposne):` This is not the error message, but if your actual code is like this, it wont work, unless you use `resposne` instead of `response` on your method.

Comment: `from scrapy.http import TextResponse as response` This may actually cause confusion on your code.

Comment: lord almighty this is why you shouldn't  code at 4 in the morning.